# materializecss | explode JSON string form Chips into array to INSERT to mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, materialize

I have the following code to send `chipsData` from chips to an input form.

```
        onChipAdd: (event, chip, modal) => {
             var chipsData = M.Chips.getInstance($('.chips')).chipsData;
             var chipsDataJson = JSON.stringify(chipsData);
             $('#ModalEdit #userEventData').val(chipsDataJson);
         },
         onChipSelect: () => {

         },
         onChipDelete: () => {
             var chipsData = M.Chips.getInstance($('.chips')).chipsData;
             var chipsDataJson = JSON.stringify(chipsData);
             $("#userEventData").val(chipsDataJson);
         }
  }
```

The form input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userEventData" id="userEventData" value="">
```

When I echo it I receive a string as follow: `[{"tag":"name1"},{"tag":"name2"}]`

I am looking for a solution to transfer it from a string to an array for later insert it to a database.
Any ideas?

*I already checked other Question and could find any solution. 
([How to store and retrieve materializecss chips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342931/how-to-store-and-retrieve-materializecss-chips))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are getting is so called [JSON](https://www.json.org/) encoded data. You can decode it in PHP using the [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode) function, which will (in your case) give you a two-dimensional array to work with:

```php
$json = '[{"tag":"name1"},{"tag":"name2"}]'
var_export(json_decode($json, true));
```

output:

```php
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'tag' => 'name1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'tag' => 'name2',
  ),
)
```

Note that I passed `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode()` since I like to work with arrays rather than objects.

Comment: Thank you! I actually try it before and for some reason I couldn’t get it to work.